# data scraping with python

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hi I'm trying to scrape all the data points that are in this url https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/coord/a18.dat

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/coord/a18.dat"

page = requests.get(url)
x = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

df = pd.DataFrame(x)
df.to_excel("air_foil.xlsx")
```

I've tried this code but `x` is just a long list that consist of one element.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use `pandas`, you can just use `pd.read_table(url)` or `pd.read_csv(url)`, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/coord/a18.dat"

df = pd.read_csv(url, header=None, skiprows=1, sep='  ', engine='python')
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
df =  pd.read_table(url, header=None, skiprows=1, sep='  ', engine='python')
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
df.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False, header=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to get this data:

```
r = requests.get("https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/coord/a18.dat")
print(r.tetx)
```

you will see what inside (string).

Then you need create a list and put to Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([el.split() for el in r.text.split("\r\n")[1:]])
```